# If ObjectId is stored in _id field, is there any reason to still have a timestamp field?

Tags: sql, database, mongodb, nosql, objectid

THe ObjectId captures the date and time the document is created. So what reason is there to still have the timestamp field?

Comment: It depends on what is the "meaning" of the `timestamp` field. Yes, you can rely on ObjectId in `_id` to get the document's creation datetime. However, a common use case for a timestamp field will be storing the last updated datetime; which objectId cannot fulfill this purpose.

Comment: A TTL index cannot automatically expire documents based on an ObjectId